# How to get primary key after calling ActiveRecord save() method PRADO?

Tags: php, activerecord, primary-key, prado

I am starting out with PRADO php framework and i have a quick question: How to get the Primary Key of the last inserted record? My codes are as follow:

```
$studentRecord = new StudentRecord;
$studentRecord->Name = $this->txtName->SafeText;
$studentRecord->ContactNumber = $this->txtContactNo->SafeText;
$studentRecord->save();
// $studentId = ???
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Prado but normally with Active Record pattern implementations the objects are refreshed when saved. Does `$record->id` (or whatever your pk col is) not work?